# JS: How to create nested object from array of objects

Tags: javascript

How would I iterate through an array of objects being returned in an API response and dynamically create a nested object that groups those objects by date? Let me use an example to further explain:

I have the following array of objects:

```
var objectsArray = [ obj1, obj2, obj3 ]
```

Objects are as follow:

```
       var obj1 = {
            date: "8/25/23",
            id: "Guid1",
            imgUrl: "www.img1.com",
        }

        var obj2 = {
            date: "8/25/23",
            id: "Guid2",
            imgUrl: "www.img2.com",
        }
        
        var obj3 = {
            date: "8/30/23",
            id: "Guid3",
            imgUrl: "www.img3.com",
        }
```

I need to dynamically create a nested object that groups the array of objects by date like this:

```
        var objWithoutDubplicateDates = {
            "8/25/23": {
                images: [obj1.imgUrl, obj2.imgUrl]
            },
            "8/30/23": {
                images: [obj1.imgUrl]
            }
        };
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can try to use a `reduce` operation using the array. See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qc0L9myp/

Comment: PSA: It's 2023 and time to learn about `let` and `const`.

Comment: @Jhilton You can post your comment as answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create nested object from array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000286/create-nested-object-from-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `reduce`.

```
const groupedByDate = objectsArray.reduce(
  (groupedObjects, object) => ({
    // Up to this point in the loop, copy all the previous groupings (empty obj if first loop)
    ...groupedObjects,
    // Add a new key set to the date of the current object being iterated
    [object.date]: {
      // Add the image of the current object to the images array, whilst also retaining any previously added against this date, if there were any
      images: [...(groupedObjects[object.date]?.images ?? []), object.imgUrl],
    },
  }),
  // Initialiser for `groupedObjects` is empty object.
  {},
)
```

With your sample inputs, logging  `groupedByDate` outputs:

```
{
    "8/25/23": {
        "images": [
            "www.img1.com",
            "www.img2.com"
        ]
    },
    "8/30/23": {
        "images": [
            "www.img3.com"
        ]
    }
}
```